# Error when remote debugging a C++ app running on Linux machine with gdbserver

Tags: visual-studio-2017, gdb, remote-debugging, gdbserver, makefile

I'm trying to get the remote debugging to work on Visual Studio 2017 in Windows. I'm using the `gdbserver` option in Visual Studio project properties. The project is a `make file` project created in Visual Studio 2017. I'm getting following error in the output window.

[image]

And getting following error in Linux Console output window

[image]

What could be the reason for these errors?

Comment: Suggest you switch debugging from `gdbserver` to `gdb` mode. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46890920/debugging-library-code-with-visual-studios-linux-support/46909617#46909617

Comment: Infact, that's what I tried first. I have another stackoverflow question on that.

Comment: @stanthomas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49901105/error-when-visual-studio-remote-debugging-with-gdb